# Force idea to use nice typescript imports from node_modules

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

Now when importing something from node_modules I get something like:

```
import {OnInit} from '../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';
```

or (If i change settings)

```
import {OnInit} from 'node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';
```

And what I want is obvious

```
'@angular/core';
```

(After import I can modify import to nice version and it works. So I think this is related to some Idea settings/folder excusion/...)

Comment: what IDEA version do you work with, what do your path mappings in `tsconfig.json` look like?

Comment: please add this as answer so I can accept

Comment: it was not the answer, just questions... Looks similar to a known [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37987), fixed in recent updates, so upgrading IDEA might help

Comment: yes update helped and it is answer

Comment: I see, thanks for clearing it up:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be [WEB-37987](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37987), fixed in recent IDEA update. Please try upgrading the IDE